# Can I programmatically trigger ios unavailable screen?

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native, mobile, rect

I would like to programmatically trigger iphone unavailable screen(like when you miss your password for couple of time iphone locks your screen), with specific amount of time.
Is there some that can do so?

I am trying to find suitable API that can lock my iphone screen without me being able to unlock it.

Comment: Consider for a moment how a malicious developer might bury this deep in their code as a time bomb to brick millions of devices and you'll likely realize why this doesn't exist as an API.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, the answer is **no**. However, it is possible through the use of something called a `Configuration profile`. However, [Configuration profiles are for enterprise use only](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/configuring_multiple_devices_using_profiles).

Organizations can set up and manage devices on a large scale. These organizations can use mobile device management (MDM) [to send specific instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/commands_and_queries) to devices with the profiles installed.

Among these is [Lock a Device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/lock_a_device)
. Apple's description:

> You can display a message and phone number on the Lock screen if the user has set a passcode for the device, it isn’t a shared iPad device, and it isn’t in Lost Mode. In macOS, this command uses the Find My framework to lock a device, and fails if there’s no recovery partition on the device.

So, no, **you can't**. Administrators managing enrolled devices **can** do something similar.